# Spinner default no selection when data fetched from json

Tags: android, json, gson, android-spinner

Hi I asked this question before.But i didn't got a proper solution. I have a spinner which will load data from json.After selecting any item from spinner then it will post zeroth postition value again to another API.Everyting works fine.But my problem is I want  defaultly no slection for spinner.I added a string  named "no selection" to to zeroth position but it is not working.Please help me to implement this.

**My spinner**

```
   void getList(){

            final Common common = new Common();
            int a= 100;
            String webService = "API/Employee/GetList";
            String postData = "";
            String[] dataColumns = {"ID",//0
                    "Code",//1
                    "Name" ,//2

            };
            Runnable postThread = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Spinner
                    int a= 0;
                    ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i=0;i<common.dataArrayList.size();i++){
                        String[] data=new String[3];
                        data[0]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[0];
                        data[1]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[1];
                        data[2]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[2];

                        List.add(data);
                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<List.size();i++){
                        Names.add(List.get(i)[1]+" - "+List.get(i)[2]);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Insert.this, R.layout.item_spinner_black, Names);
                    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner);
                    Spinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

//I added below code but it not working 

    //              dataAdapter.insert(getString(R.string.selectemp), 0);
                    Spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


                }
```

**My Post Data**

```
  postData="{\"Title\":\""+title.getText().toString()
            +"\",\"Spinnervalue\":\""+List.get(Spinner.getSelectedItemPosition())[0]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ANDROID > How to set JSON Data with Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301256/android-how-to-set-json-data-with-spinner)

Comment: @Kamalesh Bro its not setting json data to spinner...Its about default value to null

Comment: https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-spinner-hint.html

Comment: @vm345 bro my data is fetched from json...I cant modify that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a dummy value.And It worked fine.

```
ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Insert.this, R.layout.item_spinner_black, Names);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner);
                Spinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

                 String[] data = new String[3];

            data[0]="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
            data[1]="Select";
            data[2]="Name";

            List.add(data);





                for (int i=0;i<common.dataArrayList.size();i++){
                    String[] data=new String[3];
                    data[0]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[0];
                    data[1]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[1];
                    data[2]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[2];

                    List.add(data);
                }
                for(int i=0;i<List.size();i++){
                    Names.add(List.get(i)[1]+" - "+List.get(i)[2]);
                }
```

Spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

Answer (score 1):

I think its help you.

```
 ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Names.add("no selection");
   for (int i=0;i<common.dataArrayList.size();i++){
                        String[] data=new String[3];
                        data[0]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[0];
                        data[1]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[1];
                        data[2]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[2];

                        List.add(data);
                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<List.size();i++){
                        Names.add(List.get(i)[1]+" - "+List.get(i)[2]);
                    }
```

Comment: bro it will show "no selection". But the problem is it wil pass the value of position zero

Comment: bro if i dont click on spinner it should not pass the value.After the change suggested by you, it will show "no selection " in spinner.But it wil pass the value of data jut below it

Comment: Okay i got it ,You want if user is not selecting any value of spinner then no any data will pass.Am i right?

Comment: Yes bro..Thats it

Comment: Then you just validate the data of spinner before sending if spinner seelcted data is no selection then don't  pass the data.

   String nameData = (String)spinnerName.getSelectedItem();

Comment: I have given sir.

Comment: Bro iam little bit confused...Where should i place String nameData = (String)spinnerName.getSelectedItem(); ?

Comment: String nameData = (String)spinnerName.getSelectedItem();
        if(nameData.equalsIgnoreCase("no selection"))
        {
            //you pass own data
        }else
        {
            //pass spinner data
        }

Comment: Yes bro i did added this portion...But how to pass that value to postdata? ie; inside if conition? Sorry for disturbing you...Iam not that good,

Comment: In post data it is List.get(Spinner.getSelectedItemPosition())[0]}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the initialization of your adapter. So when you add later the data, it will not have pre-selected item.

**Edit:**

I reordered your current code.

```
void getList(){
            final Common common = new Common();
            int a= 100;
            String webService = "API/Employee/GetList";
            String postData = "";
            String[] dataColumns = {"ID",//0
                    "Code",//1
                    "Name" ,//2

            };
            Runnable postThread = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Spinner
                    int a= 0;
                    ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Insert.this, R.layout.item_spinner_black, Names);
                    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner);
                    Spinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

//I added below code but it not working 

    //              dataAdapter.insert(getString(R.string.selectemp), 0);
                    Spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                    for (int i=0;i<common.dataArrayList.size();i++){
                        String[] data=new String[3];
                        data[0]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[0];
                        data[1]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[1];
                        data[2]=common.dataArrayList.get(i)[2];

                        List.add(data);
                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<List.size();i++){
                        Names.add(List.get(i)[1]+" - "+List.get(i)[2]);
                    }
}
```

Comment: @AndroDevil indeed because I don't know where this variables came from. But the what I am saying is the order on how you initialized your adapter. I'll edit my code for you.

Comment: Bro what data you want? I will povide. Please help me bro

Comment: @AndroDevil I've update my answer, can you try it once again? Thanks

Comment: bro i tried your answer...defaultly it is not showing anything on spinner.Thats ok but whenever i proceed it gets crashed at the postdata i given..If we select anything on spinner, its work

Comment: bro ..Is it due to this line.  "getSelectedItemPosition())[0]"

Comment: Bro...are you there

Comment: @AndroDevil Of course, it will crash because you haven't selected anything, so when you try to call `getSelectedItemPosition` it returns `-1`.

Comment: Bro so..what wil i do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174697/discussion-between-dr3k-and-androdevil).